# textbox values won't assign to a variable in vba

Tags: vba, variables, textbox

I was running tests on my software today and found that some of the values it was producing weren't correct.

I decided to step through the code and noticed that the variables I had assigned to textbox values on my userform when hovered over said empty, even though when hovering over the textbox assigned to it, the value inputted by the user showed.

For Example,

```
n = BiTimeSteps_TextBox.Value
```

when hovered over

```
n = empty
```

even though

```
BiTimeSteps_TextBox.Value = 2
```

when hovered over.

So say I have a formula shortly after that says

```
d = n*2 ,
```

n when hovered over says empty and d is made 0 when it shouldn't be.

Someone told me if I switch it around to

BiTimeSteps_TextBox.Value = n

it should be recognised but it is still not.

What could possibly be causing this?

See full code below: (it aims to price options using the binomial tree pricing method)

```
S = BiCurrentStockPrice_TextBox.Value
X = BiStrikePrice_TextBox.Value
r = BiRisk_Free_Rate_TextBox.Value
T = BiexpTime_TextBox.Value
Sigma = BiVolatility_TextBox.Value
n = BiTimeSteps_TextBox.Value

Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim p, V, u, d, dt As Double


dt = T / n ' This finds the value of dt
u = Exp(Sigma * Sqr(dt)) 'formula for the up factor
d = 1 - u 'formula for the down factor

'V value of option

'array having the values
Dim bin() As Double 'is a binomial arrays, it stores the value of each node, there is a loop

'work out the risk free probability

p = (1 + r - d) / (u - d)

'probability of going up

ReDim bin(n + 1) As Double

'it redims the array, and n+1 is used because it starts from zero
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''European Call

If BiCall_CheckBox = True Then

    For i = 0 To n 'payoffs = value of option at final time

        bin(i + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(0, (u ^ (n - i)) * (d ^ i) * S - X) 

       'It takes the max payoff or 0

       Cells(i + 20, n + 2) = bin(i + 1) 'to view payoffs on the isolated column on the right

    Next i


End If

'european put

If BiPut_CheckBox = True Then

    For i = 0 To n 'payoffs = value of option at final time

        bin(i + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(0, X - (S * (u * (n - i)) * (d * i))) 

        ' European Put- It takes the max payoff or 0

        Cells(i + 20, n + 2) = bin(i + 1) 'to view payoffs on the isolated column on the right

    Next i

End If

For k = 1 To n 'backward column loop

    For j = 1 To (n - k + 1) 'loop down the column loop

        bin(j) = (p * bin(j) + (1 - p) * bin(j + 1)) / (1 + r)

        Cells(j + 19, n - k + 2) = bin(j) 
        '' print the values along the column, view of tree

    Next j

Next k

Worksheets("Binomial").Cells(17, 2) = bin(1) ' print of the value V
BiOptionPrice_TextBox = bin(1)
```

Comment: Assignments are not done until **after** the line has run, so put a beak on the next line and then check the values of the line you're interested in.

Comment: Where are you declaring the type for `n`? Also note that `Dim x, y, z as integer` creates x and y as variant and only z as integer.

Comment: "Someone told me if I switch it around to

BiTimeSteps_TextBox.Value = n"  This is 100% incorrect. This assigns the value of `n` to the TextBox, not the other way around, which is what you want.

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` in your code module?